# Get Route Without Parameters with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've this routing schema

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path="/admin" component={AdminApp} onEnter={AdminApp.authCheck} >
    <Route path="/admin/new" component={NewPostAdmin} />
    <Route path="/admin/posts" component={PostsAdmin}>
        <IndexRoute component={PostsAdminList}/>
        <Route path="/admin/posts/:page" component={PostsAdminList} />
        <Route path="/admin/posts/edit/:newsId" component={EditPostAdmin} />
    </Route>
</Route>
<Route component={MainApp}>
    <Route path="/" component={HomeApp} / >
    <Route path="/:page" component={HomeApp} / >
    <Route path="/notizie/:newsId" component={SinglePost} / >
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} / >
</Route>
</Router>
```

The route "/admin/posts/2" will render the second page of a list, at the bottom there is a navigation menu with Link elements to the previous or successive pages (3,4,5 etc. or the / route path that is the first page)

To create this menu i have to know inside the route "/admin/posts/:page" the basepath of the parent route, but in the props there is not an "indexroute" object

How can i resolve this problem? I could set the path in code obviously , but i want to reuse this component so this is not a viable solution

Edit: I could use regex to splice the string from location.pathname, but i don't really like this solution

Answer (score 0):

Given `<Route path="/admin/posts/:page" component={PostsAdminList} />`, `PostsAdminList` component will receive a prop called [`params`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#params) and you can access the `page` by `this.props.params.page`.